# lightbox and jquery conflict

Tags: lightbox, jquery

I need help regarding the script. lightbox works properly but jQuery not working. am totally confused what to do???

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js2/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js2/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js2/lightbox_s.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() 
jQuery("#menu_btn").mouseover(function() {
jQuery("#menu").stop(true, false).animate({
                'bottom': '-10px'
            }, 500);

});

jQuery("#menu_btn").mouseout(function() {
jQuery("#menu").stop(true, false).animate({
                'bottom': '-50px'
            }, 500);
});



jQuery("#menu").mouseover(function() {
jQuery("#menu").stop(true, false).animate({
                'bottom': '-10px'
            }, 500);

});

jQuery("#menu").mouseout(function() {
jQuery("#menu").stop(true, false).animate({
                'bottom': '-50px'
            }, 500);

});
});

</script>
```

I do not have a choice rather I post this question... I have found same thing i.e. jQuery.noConflict() to use but its not working together.

I need help in this regard.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `noConflict` is secondry.

The main issue here is that `jQuery` **has to be loaded before you include** `lightbox`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js2/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js2/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js2/lightbox_s.js"></script>
```

First include `jquery` and include `lightbox` after that as the latter is dependent on the former.